# How to "manage" bitnami pootle stack

Tags: django, bitnami

I have issues with an installed bitnami pootle stack. How do I have to configure django-admin.py --settings=pootle.settings to enable the pootle commands found at: [pootle:commands](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/pootle/commands)

Which is the correct path for the settings file?
/opt/pootle-2.1.6-1/apps/pootle/etc/pootle/localsettings.py?
/opt/pootle-2.1.6-1/apps/pootle/lib/pootle/settings.py?

Thanks&Regards

Comment: Has anyone solved to call refresh_stats or other commands via comand line with the bitnamit pootle stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already replied in the BitNami forums but I also reply here for reference (I just found the question):

You can run administration commands to manage pootle from django-admin.py. To do this, you have to specify the pootle settings and path while executing django-admin.py. So, you can check your available pootle commands running:

```
cd /your_installdir/
./use_pootle
django-admin.py help --settings=pootle.settings --pythonpath=/your_installdir/apps/pootle/lib/
```

And you can use, for instance, refresh_stats doing:

```
cd /your_installdir/
./use_pootle
django-admin.py refresh_stats --settings=pootle.settings --pythonpath=/your_installdir/apps/pootle/lib/
```

If you want to create a cron task, you can specify the bundled Python:

```
/your_installdir/python/bin/python /your_installdir/apps/django/bin/django-admin.py
```